# JBOSS domain mode, run on specific IP

Tags: java, jboss, cluster-computing, jboss7.x

I'm trying to pass this tutorial about clustering in JBOSS http://blog.akquinet.de/2012/06/29/managing-cluster-nodes-in-domain-mode-of-jboss-as-7-eap-6/
and I got stuck on running JBOSS on specific IP like

```
domain.bat --host-config=host-master.xml -Djboss.bind.address.management=192.168.0.1
```

I can run only on 127.0.0.1 or 192.168.0.100 IP addresses. What I need to do for running server on different local addresses? Is it possible at all?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all. I've found solution. In windows I can assign virtual IPs to my Network interface, and then I access to them from localhost.

Answer (score 6):

In Jboss7/EAP6, there are two jboss properties related to the IP address bindings: *jboss.bind.address* and *jboss.bind.address.management*. The first one let you specify the IP address from where JBoss will expose the applications, and the second one let you specify the IP address from where Jboss will expose the management console.

By default (if not defined) Jboss will listen for requests (both, from applications and management) from localhost (that's 127.0.0.1, the loopback interface). If you want to be able to access Jboss from the network, you'll have to set those properties to the IP from where you want JBoss to be accessible (in general, that's the IP of the machine where you've the JBoss, but in case you've several network interfaces in that machine, you can specify one of those IP for the management and the other for the applications). For example, if you want the management console to be accessible from the IP 127.0.0.1 (localhost), and the applications in general from the IP 192.168.1.26, you should specify:

```
-Djboss.bind.address=192.168.1.26
-Djboss.bind.address.management=127.0.0.1
```

So you'll be able to access your applications from the address: `http://192.168.1.26:8080` (where 8080 is the default port for applications).
And the management console from the addres: `http://127.0.0.1/9990` (where 9990 is the default port for the management).

And answering your last question, if you want to make it all accessible from all the available interfaces in your machine, you've to set those properties to the broadcast IP, that's: 0.0.0.0 . This way you'll be able to access your Jboss from localhost as well from all other available network interfaces in the server. But keep in mind that it's not advisable due to security reasons.

Comment: Appreciate ur answer, but I actually wanna know how to create this additional network interfaces for running JBOSS on different local IPs. Have u any suggestions?

Comment: The network interfaces are not really "created". You'll have a network interface for every network card you've installed in your system (that's a hardware device), and for each of those an IP in the network. For example an average machine usually includes one ethernet network card and a wireless network card, so to connect that machine to a network you can use one or both network cards setting up an IP for each of them, the way to do it depends on the OS you're using.

Comment: On the other hand, the Operating Systems, independently of the physical network cards , usually include the loopback interface (127.0.0.1) which sends all the packages to the own machine, and it's software implemented (but you can't access the machine externally using this interface, since it's only visible by the own machine).